# How to Posting Json object as request and getting jsonArray in android using Volley Library?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am new to Volley Libary can you guide how to get the JSONArray response for JSONObject as the request.

Comment: Please make the question clear? Do you want to get JSON Array then use JSON array request.

Comment: but I have to post JSON object as a request  JsonArrayRequest 
            jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject , new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
    RequestQueue MyRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);

    String u = your url;
    StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, u, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {



                try {

                    JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);  // getting response object
                    JSONObject data = res.getJSONObject("Response");
                    login_userid = data.getString("_id");    //get the string
                    Ins_name = data.getString("Inscube_Name");
                    User_Email = data.getString("Email");
                    Color_code = data.getString("Color_Code");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }




            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() { //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(Register.this, " " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> para = new HashMap<String, String>();

            para.put("",my);   //put your post string here
            para.put("", reg_email);
            para.put("", reg_pass);
            para.put("", my);

            return para;
        }
    };

    MyStringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(8000, 3, 2));

    MyRequestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can easily modify this constructor and add to `JsonArrayRequest`.

```
public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                            Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
                errorListener);
    }
```

Comment: Create a CustomJSONArray class, Here is the explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235567/volley-jsonarrayrequest-with-jsonobject-as-parameter